# gif image not show in react-native IOS app

Tags: image, react-native

I am using react-native v 0.42.0

```js
<Image source={{uri: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/JQ3IMbDi5Jkw8/giphy.gif'}} style={styles.image} />
```

gif not show...

thanks!

Comment: Are you using width and height in your image style?

Comment: Styles were missing. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add height/width to your `<Image>`:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/JQ3IMbDi5Jkw8/giphy.gif'}} style={{width:100,height:100}} />
```